# Is there any way to define a private class in Java which only other classes in the same package can access it?

Tags: java, oop, private, java-package

I've always had this question on top of my mind that why defining `private` classes within a package in Java is not possible like the way we can define it in a `namespace` in `.Net`.

Let's say I have a `ds` package in my Java Project. I have two classes in the names of `Stack` and `Queue` inside this package. Both of these classes need to make use of another class in the name of `ListNode`. `ListNode` is only required by other classes in the `ds` package, and it shouldn't be exposed to classes outside of the `ds` package.

I can define the `ListNode` as an inner classes. But in this case, I should define it in both `Stack` and `Queue` classes, and it's also redundant. Is there any design pattern to work around this? If not, please someone at least explain me why this is not possible in Java!

Comment: package private = no access modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.

```
Access Levels
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public       Y        Y        Y          Y
protected    Y        Y        Y          N
no modifier  Y        Y        N          N
private      Y        N        N          N
```

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can look into package private classes.
[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

If you omit the public/private/protected from your class it is only accessible by other classes in the same package